# Measuring average distance between two different attributes using QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, quickosm

I am trying to show the statistical significance of two QuickOSM attributes - school location and fast food restaurants.

I am then trying to relate that to overall obesity levels for boroughs in London. I am a beginner with GIS so I am struggling to find out what tools I could use to reflect this. Additionally, through my own trial and error I am encountering a few errors when trying out 'Join by distance to nearest attribute' and nearest neighbour analysis which is producing figures in the 1000's.

Comment: Dude, how about you refine one of your existing questions, instead of posting slight variations without much additional information?

Comment: To be honest, I know so little about the software at this point I'm not sure how best to explain it all. Would images help out?

Comment: Then I strongly suggest you work through the [training manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/index.html) and/or take a course.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to take a step back from the software for a bit and go learn some spatial statistics (specifically read up on spatial correlation), which can then help guide you in the proper tool(s) to use (there are many different potential techniques to use). The answers to this [very similar question posted on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_of_existing_spatial_statistical_tools_or_approaches_that_can_be_used_to_calculate_the_spatial_correlation_between_two_variables) give a number of different algorithms and related literature to read.

'Join by distance to nearest attribute' and nearest neighbour analysis are not going to give you what you are looking for.